# How do I install CalenderProvider.apk and Calendar.apk in a Froyo emulator?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, installation, calendar, android-emulator

I'm trying to code something using the calendar-functionality. As there is no support in the emulator, I tried to install the missing apks for CalenderProvider and Calendar. I found a [tutorial](http://blog.stefan-macke.com/2011/12/04/how-to-add-the-calendar-application-to-the-android-emulator-running-android-2-2-froyo/), but that doesn't work as expected. As I need to code for Froyo the tutorial sounded perfect, but the installation of the files in the linked ZIP-file looks like this:

```
G:\>"C:\Program Files\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe" install CalendarProvider.apk
367 KB/s (331864 bytes in 0.882s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/CalendarProvider.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]

G:\>"C:\Program Files\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe" install Calendar.apk
764 KB/s (243369 bytes in 0.311s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Calendar.apk
Success

G:\>
```

Regarding `INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE` I learned that it has got to do something with the ROM. As I don't have anything else I'm lost here.

Can anyone please help me to circumvent that error message or can provide a working combo for the two apks for Froyo?

Comment: There is all you need in the emulator... Why there wouldn't be a calendar app ? Beware of the API version you use and the API you run... I never launched a froyo emulator, but there was a calendar in gingerbread.

Comment: @Shywim All I can say is that there is no calendar app in the emulator. I'm not too familiar with all the details, but that's my situation.

Comment: I don't know where you've picked those files from, but as Shywim already pointed out, they must match your platform. If they are taken from GApps, they must be from their Froyo archive in your case.

Comment: @sjngm: Did you set the emulator's target to [Google's API](http://puu.sh/6AbPK.png)? If not, maybe it will solve your problem (just a guess, but since CalendarProvider is in gapps packages...)

Comment: @Shywim I only have "Android 2.2 - API Level 8" in the list. So I guess you want me to install the "Google APIs" from the SDK Manager?

Comment: @sjngm: Yes, that's it :)

Comment: @Shywim OK, after installing it I created a new AVD and was able to install the two packages successfully. Thanks.

Comment: @sjngm: I'll put it as an anwser so you can mark your question as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you downloaded the **Google APIs** corresponding to your API level in the *SDK Manager* and that you set your **AVD's target** on Google APIs. This version of the API is needed for the CalendarProvider (for sync functions with Google I imagine).

[image]

Comment: No, synchronisation is somewhere else. It doesn't work out of the box. There's a [blog](http://senk9.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/how-to-install-google-apps-gapps-on-your-android-device-phone/) and a [download page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Gapps). Now I have a problem with read-only file system.